# Remove specific value in a string with SQL or grafana

Tags: mysql, sql, grafana

Displaying some data using free version of grafana. The string that has to be displayed looks like this: `5555.7777`, but I only want to display `5555`.

Are there any functions to remove `.7777` in SQL or grafana, so that the value that will be displayed only looks like this: `5555`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `floor()` to remove the decimal points:

```
select floor(val)
```